# Eclipse Checkstyle - unable to parse configuration stream

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, checkstyle

Trying to add suppressions.xml to my checkstyle. However I am not able to pick the Workspace-Path to my suppressions.xml File.

```
<module name="SuppressionFiler">
<property name="file" value="${workspace_loc}/com.test.checkstyle/conf/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

I always get an Error with:

> Error running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project
>   'Checkstyle_Test'. unable to parse configuration stream - Property
>   ${workspace_loc} has not been set.

I also don't have access to ${buildir}.

How can I find out the workspace-project directory?

Edit: I am finding the suppressions.xml, if I type in the total path.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess you need to use `${config_loc}/suppressions.xml`. `${config_loc}` is a variable of Eclipse and it will refer to the same directory where the `checkstyle.xml` is present.

Comment: ty did work. i also had to add 'conf' folder to my build.properties, as bin.includes

Comment: Glad to know. Will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `workspace_loc`, you can use `config_loc` as:  `${config_loc}/suppressions.xml`.

`${config_loc}` is a variable of Eclipse and it will refer to the same directory where the `checkstyle.xml` is present.